# The limit results by using Taylor series of of $\mathrm{csch}^{2}(x)$

Tags: integration, limits, taylor-expansion

If we know Taylor's series of $\mathrm{csch}^{2}(x)$   as below

$$\mathrm{csch}^2x= {\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x^2}{15}-\frac{2x^4}{189}+\frac{x^6}{675}+O(x^8)}$$

We want to see a limit result by using Taylor series method.

$$\lim_{{u\to \infty}} \frac{\int_{0}^{u} x^{0.2}(\mathrm{csch}^{2}(x)-1/x^{2}) \space dx}{\int_{0}^{u} x^{0.8}(\mathrm{csch}^{2}(x)-1/x^{2}) \space dx
}
$$

Could we follow the way below by substituting  $u=1/y$, which  $y→0^+$ here?

Thus, we obtain the result $0$:

$$\lim_{{y\to 0^+}} \frac{\int_{0}^{1/y} x^{0.2}(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x^2}{15}-\frac{2x^4}{189}+\frac{x^6}{675}) \space dx}{\int_{0}^{1/y} x^{0.8}(-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{x^2}{15}-\frac{2x^4}{189}+\frac{x^6}{675}) \space dx
}=0
$$

Thank you for kind comment.

Comment: The Taylor series you present is only useful for small values of $x$. However, you want to use it in an integral where the upper limit of integration goes to infinity. This method clearly fails, because higher terms now start to explode and hence there is no convergence at all.

Comment: Using analytical continuation, one can show that
$$I(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^\alpha\left(\frac1{\sinh^2x}-\frac1{x^2}\right)dx=2^{1-\alpha}\Gamma(1+\alpha)\zeta(\alpha), \,\alpha\in(0;1)$$
Hence,
$$\frac{I(\alpha)}{I(1-\alpha)}=2^{1-2\alpha}\frac{\sin\pi\alpha}{\pi}\,\frac{\alpha\,\Gamma^2(\alpha)}{1-\alpha}\,\frac{\zeta(\alpha)}{\zeta(1-\alpha)};\,\,\alpha\in(0;1)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav. thanks. It means my limit result with Taylor series does not work here, yes ?  (as M. Wind wrote). Thanks for your last comment.

Comment: No, it does not work. As @M. Wind explained, you are not allowed to use asymptotics at $x\to0$
 to evaluate an integral with the upper bound $x\to\infty$

Comment: @M. Wind  and  Svyatoslav many thanks  for your kind comment.